# vue-observe-visibility - makes api call to every page all at once

Tags: vue.js, intersection-observer

I am using vue and have installed the npm package `vue-observe-visibility`. I currently have placed the `v-observe-visibility="visibilityChanged"` onto a Select list `<option>`;

In the `visibilityChanged` method I have this

```
visibilityChanged (isVisible) {
      if (!isVisible) {return}
      this.isVisible = isVisible
      this.page++;

      this.$emit('getMoreData', this.page)
    },
```

So the page increments and emits an event which calls a `getMoreData()` method and returns paginated data in increments of 15 per page.

Method

```
getMoreData (page) {
      if(page > this.lastPage) {return}
      axios.get(`${this.userDataUrl}?page=${page}`).then(response => {
        this.items.push(...response.data.data);
        this.lastPage = response.data.last_page;
      });
    },
```

HTML

```
  <div>
    <select onfocus='this.size=10;' onblur='this.size=1;' onchange='this.size=1; this.blur();'> //to make select have scrollable feature
      <option
          v-if="items.length" v-observe-visibility="visibilityChanged"
          v-for="item in items"
          value="item.id"
          :key="item.id"
      >
        <slot name="item" v-bind:item="item" />
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>
```

The issue is that as soon as i open the drop down, the getMoreData method is called for every page so it causes a refresh after opening the select list. I see in my Network tab that it makes a call immediately to `?page=2,3,4` etc... How do I make this only call the next page once I scroll down far enough into the next page?

Answer (score 1):

Move the `v-observe-visibility="visibilityChanged"` onto an object (`<div>`) that sits underneath your items on the page, not on every item. Every item is always visible, thus it triggers the load of every page. Also, I'm not sure using this in a select is the best use case.